# Emit Win32Icon with Roslyn

Tags: c#, icons, roslyn

How do I give my roslyn compiler output an icon?

In codedom I can simply use the CompilerOptions and add it as "/win32icon:"

But how to do in roslyn?

I've this already.

```
   var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(File.ReadAllText("program.cs"));
         CSharpCommandLineArguments arguments = new CSharpCommandLineArguments();
        arguments.Win32Icon = @"ICON PATH";

        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            "program",
            new[] { syntaxTree },
            new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) },
            new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication));

        ResourceWriter rs = new ResourceWriter("res.resources");

        var resourceDescription = new ResourceDescription("program.Resources.resources", () => new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("res.resources")), true);

        using (var dllStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var pdbStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var emitResult = compilation.Emit(dllStream, pdbStream, null,null, manifestResources: new [] {resourceDescription});
            if (emitResult.Success)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes("test.exe",dllStream.GetBuffer());
                Console.WriteLine("compiled");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("foutje: {0}", emitResult.Diagnostics[0].ToString());
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Thanks for the help already!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in the win32Resources options to Emit, created via [`Compilation.CreateDefaultWin32Resources`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Compilation.cs,0a15ef3b510bd984), which takes an `Stream iconInIcoFormat` parameter.

```
compilation.Emit(
    peStream: peStream,
    pdbStream: pdbStream,
    win32Resources: compilation.CreateDefaultWin32Resources(..., iconInIcoFormat: File.Open("<pathTo.ico>")))
```

A more detailed exmaple is [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Precompilation/blob/73c9a6b3deeb9f37e8f0300aa60a543dd5527825/StackExchange.Precompilation.Build/Compilation.cs#L168)